# Creating "view" of "user blogs" specific to a user

Tags: views, users, nodes

On a user "my account" page, I want to create a view block which lists the blogs created by that user only. Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are solution for it by using Contextual Filter in views. Follow this -

- Create a new content view and limit it to the content type you want.
- Uncheck "Create a page" and check "Create a block." Select the format you want.Click "Continue & edit."
- Add a contextual filter for "Content: Author uid.". Do this --

> Under "When the filter value is not available," select "Provide a
> default value," and select "User ID from URL" from the dropdown.
> Because blocks don't understand contextual filters very well, the view
> won't work properly without this default value, and all posts of the
> given content type will show on all user pages (not just the user's
> own posts).
>
> Under "When the filter value is available or a default is provided,"
> check "Specify validation criteria" and select "Basic validation" as
> the validator. Select "Hide view" from the dropdown.

- Save your view.
- Assuming that you created a block display, the block will now be available on the Blocks page. Go there and open it.
- Set your block to display on all user pages (/user/*) in the correct region. Save the block.
- Your block should now appear on all user pages, showing the content written by each user.

Let me know the result if it works fine :)

Comment: It worked absolutely fine and to the requirement. I was doing the same thing but was stuck at the contextual filter part. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: @Nikhil Welcome :)